# Render form inside topbar in all routes

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I just wanna ask about the best approach to render a form in all routes.

Basically what I want is to *allow users to login from anywhere within the site by putting the login form in the topbar*.

[image]

Currently, I have a `/login/` route whose form is built-up from `forms.py` and rendered thru a `view function`. I want to redesign the login flow to the one specified above.

Any suggestion would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Create the form in plain HTML. You don't really need `{{ form.something }}` to render the form. Just use plain HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

I am still shook as to how easy the solution was. I have been through this in Laravel before, even using vue.js, and I thought it's different here in Django and that it had to be complicated lol. Anyway, thanks @xyres for the idea.

So I just wrote my `login snippet` as plain HTML form, then let `views.py` do the rest.

**topbar.html (login snippet)**
[image]

**views.py**
[image]